# MongoDB - How to update a document with multi-level nesting

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is my document：

```
{
  "_id": NumberLong(861),
  "Name": "李四",
  "Number": "030404",
  "Answers": {
    "ModuleItems": [
      {
        "ModuleType": NumberInt(1),
        "AnswerListItems": [
          {
            "ModuleItemId": "111",
            "SRUrl": "https://file-public-ashermed.oss-cn-shanghai.aliyuncs.com/XXX.mp3",
            "ModuleItemState": NumberInt(0),
            "TestType": NumberInt(2),
            "AnswerItems": [
              {
                "_id": "222",
                "Answer": "some questions1",
                "AnswerState": NumberInt(0)
              },     
            ]
          },
          {
            "ModuleItemId": "444",
            "SRUrl": "https://file-public-ashermed.oss-cn-shanghai.aliyuncs.com/XXXX.mp3",
            "ModuleItemState": NumberInt(0),
            "TestType": NumberInt(2),
            "AnswerItems": [
              {
                "_id": "666",
                "Answer": "",
                "AnswerState": NumberInt(1)
              },            
            ]
          },     
        ],
        "LastModuleItemId": "666"
      },
      {
        "ModuleType": NumberInt(2),
        "AnswerListItems": [],
        "LastModuleItemId": "2555"
      },      
    ],
    "TotalScore": "79分"
  },
  "VisitRecordState": NumberInt(2),    
}
```

My filters:

> "_id" : NumberLong(861),Answers.ModuleItems.ModuleType = NumberInt(1), ModuleItemId= 444

I want to modify the SRUrl field of this document's elements which ModuleItemId equals 444.

Answer (score 0):

You need [positional operator `$[]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#update-nested-arrays-in-conjunction-with----) and `arrayFilters` to update element in nested arrays.

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: NumberLong(861)
},
{
  $set: {
    "Answers.ModuleItems.$[mi].AnswerListItems.$[ali].SRUrl": /* New SRUrl */
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "mi.ModuleType": 1
    },
    {
      "ali.ModuleItemId": "444"
    }
  ]
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/isVPfi7cF7X)

Comment: thank you for your answer. It's userful，but i didn't find a method contains  arrayFilters in  the frame which i am using.

Comment: Hi can I know which tool you are using?